# Why I am getting error when reading a file from file system using full path?

Tags: java, spring-boot, filesystems

I have the following to read a file from the file system, I provide to the method full file name including "c://". here is the method:

```
private Resource loadAsResource(String filename) throws MalformedURLException {     
              Path file = root.resolve(filename);
              Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
                         
              if (resource.exists() || resource.isReadable()) {
                return resource;
              }
            return null;                        
    }
```

when printing logs I found that both exist() and isReadable() return false.
here is the error show from the tomcat log:

```
cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length
```

Please also note that when I refresh the page (angular 9) the file (picture) is shown
on the screen so this is not path problem.
I have search for solution and found possible solution to use classpath but in my case I can't use it cause the requirement is to use file system. The folder can't be in the static folder cause I don't want it to be in the jar file. In production the folder should contain 140K files including pictures and videos.

Comment: A file url starts with `file://` not a drive letter.

Comment: This is the base folder C:\\Users\\john\\OneDrive\\Documents  I need to change it to what ?

Comment: `file://c:/Users/john/OneDrive/Documents` - I'm not certain that will work, but it's at least a valid file url.

Comment: the "Resource resource" hold the url you suggested URL [file:/C:/Users/john_/OneDrive/Documents...

Comment: That code looks very familiar, so I think I already asked you this: Given that you have a `Path`, why are you using [`new UrlResource(file.toUri())`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/UrlResource.html), instead of [`new PathResource(file)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/PathResource.html)?

Comment: That code looks very familiar, so I think I already asked you this: If you log the value of `file`, what do you see?

Comment: Another thing, when debugging the picture show on the screen, when I remove the debug breaking point the problem accrued.  I don't mind to wait few second any idea how to implement wait which won't lifetime loop ?

Comment: I'm trying now to write to temp file and rename it later hopefully will work, will come here with the outcome

Comment: If the code works correctly if you wait a few seconds, then obviously something has changed during that wait. Now knowing your code, I can see 2 things that might change in such a way as to make the code suddenly starting working: 1) The value of `root` changes. Logging the value of `file` would definitely show that. --- 2) The file is created by some background process that hasn't completed yet on the first call. What you're seeing is what is known as a race-condition.

Comment: Is my solution to save temp and rename sound good to you?

Comment: After renaming I get the same problem

Comment: I think it is good to place your files in your project's resource folder. Because there are some security reasons, so you won't able to get the files from the C drive.

Comment: I don't want to be in static folder, its just pictures and videos the security will be in linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like this solution but it simply works:

```
private Resource loadAsResource(String filename) {
        try {
              Path file = root.resolve(filename);
              Resource resource = new UrlResource(file.toUri());
              int i=0;
              while(!resource.exists() || !resource.isReadable()) {
                  Thread.sleep(100);
                  if (++i == 20) {
                      break;
                  }
              }
              return resource;                    
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 throw new RuntimeException("Could not read the file!");
            }       
    }
```

The loop will be break after 2 second not big deal.

Comment: [Watching a Directory for Changes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)